# Can I loop over the results of an SQL query to use each value in another query all at once in SQL Developer?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

What I want to achieve (if it is possible from SQL Developer) is that when I execute the script it do the following:

1. Run a `SELECT` statement that will return a list of IDs. *Approx 270 records.*
2. I need to use each of those IDs individually in another `SELECT` statement (in the `WHERE` clause) which will return some records. *A few of this could result in over 17,000 records and some can be one.*
3. Then each result from the second `SELECT` I want it to be exported to an excel or csv file into a folder at my pc.

I have both 'Select' ready but I don't know how to loop over the results of the first to grab each ID and use it in the second one. Also I don't know how to export automatically from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY clause.
read more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html

Comment: Thanks Al Pimenov, it was helpful.

Any suggestions about the export part?

Answer (score 0):

If the first `SELECT` returns you IDs only, and that's all you need for your second `SELECT`, just use `IN` clause providing your first `SELECT` query for the second one.
Example:

```
-- Your second select
SELECT
  col1
  ,col2
  ,col3
  ,col4
FROM
  second_table
WHERE
  some_foreign_id IN (
    -- Your first select
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      first_table
    WHERE
      some_conditions...
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion don't use PLSQL for this. In PLSQL the only way you can get an output of this by using a REFCURSOR (unless you dont use UTIL File package to do it). A simple SELECT WITH JOIN condition will suffice your requirement.

```
Test illustration

SELECT A.* FROM TABLE_A A, TABLE_B
WHERE A.COMMON_COLUMN = B.COMMON_COLUMN;
```

Hope this helped you in same way